# What is a consistent method for converting d20 SRD monster stats to Microlite20?

Tags: conversion, d20-system, microlite20

In the Monster Creation section, Microlite20 states, "Add stat bonuses to suit and as logic dictates."

I could come up with each monster's stats individually as I use them, but doing this *well* seems like it might take more effort and experimentation (not to mention time) than I want, not having GMed 3.5 before. The monsters in the M20 core are heavily influenced by the d20 SRD, and the two systems are meant to be generally compatible. Pulling stats from the d20 SRD seems like a good place to start.

The problem I'm running into is that M20 only has three stats, and d20 has six. I'd like to know if anyone has experience with a **functional, across-the-board method for boiling d20 monster stats down into just Strength, Dexterity, and Mind**. The goal here is to keep the monsters roughly the same type and intensity of challenge as they are in the d20 SRD, although I know it may not always be 1:1.

I'm primarily using the [core](https://microlite20.org/forum/index.php?action=downloads;sa=view;down=19) and the [Purest Essence](https://microlite20.org/forum/index.php?action=downloads;sa=view;down=64) documents, but I can consider material from other M20 variants, provided they're compatible with the core. Tested house rules are also acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't personally have any experience with Microlite, but just looking at the rules, you pretty much don't need to change anything. Comparing the example monsters given in the Microlite document to the monsters on the v.3.5 SRD, the numbers are *identical*, even where they shouldn't be.

For example, let's look at the Bugbear:

> Bugbear HD 3d8+3 (16 hp) AC 17 Morningstar +5 (1d8+2) or javelin +3 (1d6+2)

This is from Microlite, but is identical to the SRD. Why does a morningstar deal 1d8+2? Because it has 15 Strength. Why does it have 3d8+3 hp? Because it has 13 Constitution, for +1 hp per Hit Die. ...but there is no difference between Strength and Constitution in Microlite, so these should be the same number.

What this means, is that, if the creators don't worry about the difference, neither should you. Just use the combat stats for any 3.5 monster as written, and you'll be fine. The difficulty will be nearly identical (all characters in Microlite basically just have full Base Attack).

We do need ability scores for skills, though. For the three Microlite ability scores...

- Strength: Use whichever is higher between Strength and Constitution
- Dexterity: Same as the Dexterity on the SRD
- Mind: Take the average of Intelligence and Charisma.

As the rules state, they get a bonus equal to their hit dice to all four skills (+3 for our 3 HD bugbear), and then add an extra +3 to whichever skill you want that monster to use. You can even decide while playing, you don't even need to convert that. But in general...

- A monster with good Hide/Move Silently should use **Subterfuge**
- A monster that has lots of Knowledge skills or has a knowledge role should have **Knowledge**
- A monster that focuses on talking to players (e.g. a succubus) should have **Communication**
- *All other monsters* should have **Physical**

And that should be everything. Hope that helps!

Comment: While I appreciate the logic of this answer, it is always better to be able to back up an answer with experience.

Comment: I have extensive experience with 3.5, and design RPG systems as a hobby. I may not have played Microlite specifically, but general experience is still valid, especially when comparing the probabilities.

An attack roll from a level 1 fighter in 3.5 is d20+1 (BAB) + Str. An attack roll from a level 1 fighter in Microlite is d20+1 (level) + Str. It doesn't take much experience to see that, against an identical armor class, there is no difference between the systems in terms of difficulty.

As for skills, it uses a 3 + level, which is the same as the skill ranks in 3.5. Again, identical.

Comment: That's good to know :)